# How to create multiple sentences from a given sentence in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I want to create multiple sentences from a given sentence by jumbling words in python.

e.g. say i have a sentence "password reset successful"

Now, i need to generate various combination of sentence from the above one.

output:

```
reset password successful
successful reset password
successful password reset
password reset successful.
...
```

How to get using python

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this? As outlined on [ask], some research effort is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> sentence = "password reset successful"
>>> for sent in permutations(sentence.split()):
        print(' '.join(sent))
password reset successful
password successful reset
reset password successful
reset successful password
successful password reset
successful reset password
```

If you want in a list:

```
>>> [' '.join(sent) for sent in permutations(sentence.split())]
['password reset successful',
 'password successful reset',
 'reset password successful',
 'reset successful password',
 'successful password reset',
 'successful reset password']
```

If you don't want the original `sentence` in list:

```
>>> combs = [' '.join(sent) for sent in permutations(sentence.split())]
>>> combs.remove(sentence)
>>> combs
['password successful reset',
 'reset password successful',
 'reset successful password',
 'successful password reset',
 'successful reset password']
```

Comment: How can i apply the same technique to a column with 10 rows. it has to generate sentences for each row in the column